# Building a gem from outside of the directory

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems

I have an ordinary gem directory structure in directory `path_to_foo`:

```
path_to_foo
|-bin
 |-some_file_name
|-lib
 |-foo.rb
|-foo.gemspec
```

When I move to that directory and build the gem, it succeeds:

```
path_to_foo$ gem build foo.gemspec
```

but if try to do that from outside of the directory, it fails:

```
~$ gem build path_to_foo/foo.gemspec
WARNING:  See http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ for help
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InvalidSpecificationException)
["bin/some_file_name"] are not files
```

How can I build a gem from a gemspec from outside of the directory? I think I probably need to add something to the gemspec file.

Comment: I suspect this is because `gem build` is looking for any files referenced in the spec file relative to the directory where the build command is run, and that's why it won't find those files. Does it work if you run it with `gem build foo.gemspec --force` to skip spec validation?

Comment: It is worth to mention whether `gemspec` file was build with standard `bundle gem` or created manually. In general, the content of `foo.gemspec` should be shown, since `gem build` behaviour hardly relies on it.

Comment: Rather than modifying `gemspec` file with kinda parsing `ARGV[1]` and doing `Dir.chdir` there, the proper unix solution seems to be `pushd path_to_foo && gem build foo.gemspec && popd`. `gemspec` should not suffer from your intent to build it under alien conditions.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?
Just cd in and cd out afterwards

Comment: @eugen I tried that but it fails.